# backup/disaster recovery for AKS cluster

Tags: azure, azure-aks

How can we achieve backup/disaster recovery for AKS cluster and all resources in resource group ex.VMS,network,storage,DNS. Could someone help me with some links.I am new to azure and having confusion on these

Comment: Have you tried googling "azure aks backup/disaster recovery"?

Comment: I have searched but as I am new to azure, having confusion on these

Answer (score 0):

You can use valero for backing up look at below url https://velero.io/docs/v1.5/restic/